# Google Maps map doesn't load anymore

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have a problem with my GoogleMaps map that I added to my website.
The maps worked fine yesterday, with markers and all. Today, the code was not changed but when i load the page, markers appear but the map doesn't.

I tried to empty the cache, but it doen't work. Does anybody ever had the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Well i found the answer.
I'll answer my own question if anyone have the problem.
Apparently, the API key is optionnal but for a certain amount of requests. After a while, you will have to get a API key from Google to make it work.